Fix warning: Slots named on_foo_bar are error prone
I am getting this warning in header files from clazy-connect-by-name literally hundreds of times in a legacy project I have been supporting for 15+ years in Qt. I recently followed an upgrade path from Qt 5.15.16 to Qt 6.6.2 and am now getting this warning. The project (2 .exe and 5 .dlls)  compiles and runs fine (Qt 6.6.2, MinGW 64-bit in Windows 11) If I understand the risks, can I ignore this warning?
As I understand things from previous SO issues, the fix is to put a connect statement in the constructor of the defined class for each of these widget-action routines. Has anyone come up with maybe a macro to help this along? It would take me days to convert this in my current project.

Since it's only a warning you can simply turn them off. On the long run I would remove this auto-connect stuff as fast as possible.
